# How to compare entrySet of two maps

Tags: java, collections

I have two hashmaps and I just want to compare their keys as well as their values with each other.

```
Student stu1=new Student(1, "student_1_Name");
Student stu2=new Student(2, "student_2_Name");

Map<Integer, Student> map1= new Hashmap<Integer, Student>();
Map<Integer, Student> map2= new Hashmap<Integer, Student>();

map1.put(1, stu1);
map2.put(2, stu2);

System.out.println("is there any diff.==="+map1.entrySet().equals(map2.entrySet()));
```

As much I know:

- map.keySet()  : gives keys of map
- map.values()  : gives values of map
- map.entrySet() : gives both keys and values.

The above code snippet always gives me false. I just want to compare the values and keys of two maps. Please let me know how I can compare two maps?

Comment: What do you want to compare *exactly*? The keys and the values separately or the entries (both key and value of an entry should be equal to the key and the value of another entry).

Comment: You get false because the keys are different! One uses `1`, the other uses `2`

Comment: Not only the keys. The values are also different. So if it printed something else than `false`, something would be horribly wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Equals and hashcode for entrysets will compare instances of the Map implementation itself, not elements.

The normal mechanism is to iterate over an entry set comparing keys or values, like this :

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet())
{
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
    myBoolean = entry.getKey().equals(myOtherString);
}
```

Comment: Yaa exactly, So what should I do if I need to compare keys and values of both maps.??

also I dont want to put manual logic here..

Comment: Incorrect. Any correct `java.util.Map` implementation has an `equals(Object o)` that "Compares the specified object with this map for equality. Returns true if the given object is also a map and the two maps represent the same mappings. More formally, two maps m1 and m2 represent the same mappings if m1.entrySet().equals(m2.entrySet()). This ensures that the equals method works properly across different implementations of the Map interface."

Answer (score 0):

You must iterate over Sets. for example :

```
private boolean isEqual(map1, map2){
  for (Integer i : map1.keySet())
    if(map2.contains(i))
      if(! map1.get(k).equlas(map2.get(k)))
        return false;
    else return false;
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your sujjestion. But I said I dont want to put manual logic here... Becuase the map I have , is superMap and have so many other inner maps Or pojos object. So i just need to use something generic otherwise I have to get value of map first and then compare of inner pojo's properties

Answer (score 0):

This program:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Integer, String> map1 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    Map<Integer, String> map2 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    map1.put(2, "bbb");
    map1.put(1, "aaa");
    map2.put(1, "aaa");
    map2.put(2, "bbb");
    System.out.println(map1.entrySet().equals(map2.entrySet()));
    System.out.println(map1.equals(map2));
  }
}
```

prints

```
true
true
```

There are two significant differences from the program in the question:

1. I used `String`, not `Student`. `String` has an `equals()` and a `hashCode()` that are consistent with each other and reflect value, not instance, equality.
2. I used `java.util.HashMap`. The question program used `Hashmap`. `HashMap` has an `equals()` and a `hashCode()` that are consistent with each other and follow the `java.util.Map` contract.

I recommend checking the implementation of `equals()` and `hashCode()` in both `Student` and `Hashmap`.

Comment: I cant override equals method on student class.

Comment: @user3029929 What does its equals method do?

Comment: its not like that its doing some other job.. But at this point I cant use equals and hashcode method. As I said this is just an example.. my orignal implementation is something more generic. It code doesnt know which class or object needs to compare. Everything will serve dynamically.

I believe I should go with reflection.

Comment: By definition, calling equals (and the code I showed calls equals indirectly) is the correct, most generic way to ask an object whether it is logically equal to some other object.

Answer (score 0):

don't forget to implement hashCode + equals for Student class